# XSL Traversing Question (with Server Error:)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have, what I believe to be, an interesting situation at hand.
I have a car garage XML and am transforming it (using XSL) into HTML.

**CAR XML:**

```
<car>
   <licensePlate>Car001</licensePlate>
   <feature>
      <color>Blue</color>
      <fuel>Unleaded</fuel>
   <feature>
</car>
```

I only want to print out `<color>` & `<fuel>` but want to set the `<licensePlate>` as href in a HTML link.

**CAR XSL:**

```
<xsl:template match="car">
   <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="licensePlate"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="feature"/>
   </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="feature">
   <td>
      <a href="{preceding-sibling::licensePlate/text()}>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="color"/>
      </a>
   </td>
   <td><xsl:apply-templates select="fuel"/></td>
</xsl:template>
```

This  enables me to achieve my goal of setting the  tag as the href value.

BUT a problem occurs...all of the values of licensePlate are printed to screen.

Can someone recommend how to prevent it from printing to screen?

I have tried commenting out `<xsl:apply-templates select="licensePlate"/>` but I think this affects the `preceeding-sibling::` statement as I receive an error

I have also received this error when trying to apply a CSS `display:none`.

Thankyou for your time and patience,
Lucas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I'm assuming you have the templates for color and fuel already done.

```
<xsl:template match="car">
    <tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="feature"/>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="feature">
    <td>
        <a>
            <xsl:param name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="../licensePlate"/>
            </xsl:param>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="color"/>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fuel"/>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion: I still get the same error:
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportEception: The server sent HTTP status code -1: null.

Comment: Above I mentioned my assumption that you already have templates for color and fuel. Is this true? If so, could you post them? Any extra info would be helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You should comment out `<xsl:apply-templates select="licensePlate"/>`.
It couldn't be the cause of the error if you commented it out correctly.

Also:
`<a href="{preceding-sibling::licensePlate/text()}>` <-- yuikes!

`<a href="{../licensePlate}>`!

Comment: Alamar, thankyou for your speedy response.
Would that still work as it is not a child element within <feature> but a sibling of <feature>

Comment: @lucas: ".." means "parent", not "child".

Comment: Sure!
Access to child element would be just `{licensePlate}`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion: I still get the same error:
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportEception: The server sent HTTP status code -1: null.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="car">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="feature" />
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="feature">
   <td>
      <a href="{../licensePlate}">
        <xsl:value-of select="color" />
      </a>
   </td>
   <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="fuel" />
   </td>
</xsl:template>
```

Would produce:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <a href="Car001">Blue</a>
  </td>
  <td>Unleaded</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion: I still get the same error:
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportEception: The server sent HTTP status code -1: null.

Comment: I was missing a closing double quote. Can you try again?